# Why hostname FQDN is not set properly on Digital Ocean?

Tags: linux, dns, digital-ocean, hostname, fqdn

I've observed this issue on Ubuntu 16.04 droplets, but I suppose it happens on other Debian based droplets. More explanations below.

After creating a brand new instance, I've observed that `hostname --fqdn` does not return the FQDN (Full Qualified Domain Name) as I would expect, but only returns the hostname, without the domain name appended to it.

```
$ hostname
mydroplet
$ hostname --fqdn
mydroplet
```

I would expect to see something like this:

```
$ hostname --fqdn
mydroplet.example.com
```

This is a potentially serious problem, since many services depend on the FQDN for working properly.

How this problem can be fixed?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: `mydroplet.example.com` is ***not*** a FQDN. FQDN's end in a dot (`.`) to denote the top of the DNS tree. `mydroplet.example.com.` and `localhost.` are FQDN's. When the dot is present the resolver *should not* add suffixes to search paths. Whose DNS you use is a different story. Also see W. Richard Stevens' [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321637739).

Comment: @jww ``hostname --fqdn`` does not append a dot in the end, whatever the RFC says.

Comment: Because the dot is implicit. It is not its presence that necessarily says a name is an FQDN or not, contrary to what @jww says. See RFC 8499: "But, because every
      name eventually shares the common root, names are often written
      relative to the root (such as "www.example.net") and are still
      called "fully qualified"."

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek : That's OK. I've just showed the output of the command so that readers could understand what the problem is, what would be expected as output of the command (regardless a leading dot or not) and what should be done in order to remedy the difficulty. Thanks a lot for your explanation. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### For the impatient

These commands below fix the issue on an existing droplet:

```
echo "domain example.com" | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d/head
sudo service resolvconf restart
```

### What is the problem?

The command `hostname --fqdn` should return the FQDN (full qualified domain name), like this:

```
$ hostname --fqdn
mydroplet.example.com
```

If you don't see the FQDN but only the host name... well... you have a problem which sooner or later will hurt your application, shell scripts or services.

```
$ hostname --fqdn
mydroplet
```

Houston, we have a problem!

### Route for fixing

In a nutshell, we need to make `/etc/resolv.conf` look like this:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain example.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

If you don't see `domain example.com` in it, you will have a problem sooner or later.

You can think that it's merely a matter of editing the file, right? Not so fast! ... We cannot change this file by hand, because it is maintained by Debian itself. If you change it by hand, it will get back to its initial state by itself, sometime later.

### Creating droplets via Digital Ocean's web interface

Add the following snippet of code in the text area reserved for [cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/)'s user-data:

```
#cloud-config
manage_etc_hosts: false
write_files:
  - path: /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
    content: |
      domain example.com
runcmd:
  - service resolvconf restart
```

The snippet above guarantees that `hostname --fqdn` will return what you would expect immediately when you first log into your droplet.

Comment: Do not blindly use `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4` and this is totally irrelevant to setting the local hostname.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek :: I do not use Google DNS myself. It is just an example.